# "Time" library form Arduino show incorrect values

Tags: c++, arduino

Whenever this shows me the hour, minute and second starts at 0 (instead of the actual values). I have reviewed the documentation and should show the data from the year 1970 (timestamp)

Comment: Maybe 1970 is the start of the *epoch*.  Try adding the year 1970 to time read.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize the time of the TimeLib, the it starts with Arduino sketch initialization from 1970-01-01 00:00:00. So yes, hour is 0, minute is 0 and in setup() the second could be 0 too.

The examples of the library show different ways to initialize and synchronize time with the TimeLib.